# IOS7 GRAlertView is ignored

Tags: ios7, alertview

I have been using GRAlertView for my alerts. 
Now with IOS7 it is "ignored" totally.
Just regular AppleWanted Alerts appear :-(

Are there any solutions already found or do we have to start at point zero?
THX4uRhelp

Comment: Use the Apple standard UIAlertView. The user knows the alert view and knows how to handle it.

Comment: well .. havent been my intension..
i try CSNotificationView :-D